# preg_grep function does not find anything (php)

Tags: php, regex

I hate to ask that kind of question because the answer is either 'I am stupid' or 'there is strange problem with my computer'... (and the first one is probably the right one) But I am stuck on that :

```
$matches = preg_grep("(.+)","ThisIsATest");
error_log(count($matches), 3, "php.log");
```

The log gives me `0`, no matter what I give as a pattern... I can't understand why this `$matches` variable is always empty !

Comment: The second param of preg_grep is an array not a string

Comment: @Med: it is! parentheses can be used as delimiters

Comment: Didn't know that actually +1 for that info. (I would still avoid using parenthesis though as they just lead to confusion)

Comment: Same here, i deleted my comment to avoid confusion, but using parenthesis as delimters can  be tricky...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the error you should be getting:

```
preg_grep() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given
```

This is a way to return *one* match (and you will only have 1 in this case) with [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.preg-match.php):

```
preg_match("(.+)","ThisIsATest", $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/tShFpr)

To access the value using `$matches[0]`, you need to use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
preg_match_all("(.+)","ThisIsATest", $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

See [another demo](https://ideone.com/43qnaa)

Answer (score 2):

`preg_grep` is not for searching through a string, but an array of strings... You should probably use `preg_match` instead.

Comment: ok so the answer is 'I am stupid' ! 
However now I have one match (the log gives me `1` but when I try to display `$matches[0]` it still contains nothing.. any idea ?

Comment: @Arcyno: use [preg_match_all](https://ideone.com/43qnaa) if you want to access the match using `$matches[0]`. I updated my answer with some more information on `preg_match` and `preg_match_all`.

Comment: `preg_match` returns the essentially a boolean, 1 for matches, 0 for doesn't match, use `$matches = array(); preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);`

Comment: actually I was using it as `preg_grep` and not as it should (cf answer from stribizhev)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are just using the wrong method:

```
if (preg_match('/(.+)/', "ThisIsATest")) {
   # Successful match
} else {
   # Match attempt failed
}
```